# HTML5 placeholder showing numerical HTML encoding

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, placeholder

I have an application on Apache. My Apache is configured with default encoding ISO-8859, and I´m not able to change it because Apache suport others applications that need this.

Then, in my application I´m using numerical HTML encoding in special characters, like that: **Usu& #225;rio** (this is **Usuário**).

It´s working fine, but in placeholders and title (HTML5 elements), the interface is showing &#225 ; instead to show á.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you declared encoding in html meta tag?

Comment: Yes @Maksim <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: Is your html document html or php? Have you tried writing it in php file and defining custom header at the beginning on the file? like this: header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: PHP? It´s an application with HTML5, JavasCript and CSS3. I don't work with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I used **unicode code point** instead **numerical HTML encoding**. Take a look at UTF-8 encoding table and unicode characters [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct&unicodeinhtml=dec&htmlent=1).

Answer (score 0):

You could rename your ***.html*** file to **.php** and add following line to the first row:

```
<?php header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
```

This will send a response from server that the content which is sent is encoded in utf-8.

By adding above code nothing will be broken and you wont see any difference exept for correct encoding.

In case you need to move the site from one server to another, you can undo those steps and everything will still work as expected.

It tried to reproduce your issue with the given HTML entity and placeholder encodes the character correctly.